# Using WinSCP to connect Windows Client to Linux server

Tags: authentication, linux, sftp, windows-7

I am trying to understand how to set up an SFTP connection between Windows 7 PCs (yes, these PCs will be supported through part of next year) to a Linux Server.  I think I'm finally getting it - but it's the where to put things and how to actually connect that I'm not following.

I'm testing all of this out in a test lab before these new Linux Servers go out.  I have generated a key pair.  I've given the public key to my test server admin, who has placed it in **/root/.ssh/authorized_keys** (is this the correct location?) on the Linux server.

I have placed my private key in **\Users\user\.ssh\keyname.ppk** on my Windows PC.  Is that correct?

And now I am trying to write a test batch script that will create a .dat file with my connection command, my PUT and GET commands, and which will be called by WinSCP to connect to that server and run those commands.  If I can get this working, I will be using this same batch code and WinSCP call in several different scripts which currently use FTP, not SFTP.

What I'm not sure how do is how to connect.  I have the call to my .dat file -

```
winscp /script=\temp\sftp.dat
```

But my current authentication method is to use a username/password combination - here is the first line of the .dat file:

```
open sftp://username:password@servername -hostkey="ssh-ed25519 xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

...but username/password authentication will not be available to me.  So how do I connect with just the key pair?  Is there a particular line I need to write in place of that **open sftp** line for it to connect?

Comment: Hi and welcome to security.SE! Since this question isn't really about security _per se_, but about how to use specific software, I'm going to vote to migrate to serverfault. I think you'll get a better answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally discovered that the key location on the server is correct, the key location on the client is not strict as long as I use the -privatekey parameter with WinSCP - which I finally figured out - this is the line within sftp.dat that worked:

```
open sftp://username@servername -hostkey="ssh-ed25519 xxxxxxxxxxxx" -privatekey=\pathtoprivatekey\key.ppk
```

Got connected and finally have a better understanding of SFTP with a public key authentication.